# sprite kit swift initial slow frame rate/ lag?

Tags: swift, sprite

I've just started learning how to use sprite kit, I've almost completed my first game, however I have come across a problem which I don't really know how to solve, basically when I first load the game/scene the game is very laggy FPS drops to about 30, and movement and animations are not smooth, however soon as the first scene is finished and play again everything is super smooth? so initial load is slow, second and every load after that is fine, I need some pointing in the direction, thanks

Comment: Are you testing on Simulator or on the real device ? Also do you preload your atlases or even sounds ? And how much that lag lasts ? Through the whole gameplay, or it can be seen only initially when the game starts ?

Comment: no i don't pre load anything, and only the first game which lasts 60 secs, all games after are fine, i haven't looked into preloading atlases or sounds, thanks for the advice, will look into it now.

Comment: How do you load your resources ? Do you have any shared assets ? It may be that when loading the assets for the first time, it takes time to load. With that being said, if you reuse them later, there will be no lag because the assets are already in memory. But this is assumption because I don't see your project.

Comment: i just had to preload the atlases, it works fine now, thanks for the advice